# Release notes of Microsoft sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, office365, document

I am working on document and opened it in the Sharepoint. I saw the build version as "16.0.17319.41014" but could not find release notes in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates

I have googled, searched in multiple portals but could not find it. The latest version I could find in the notes is "16.0.16731.20462"

Can anyone help me with the latest release of Sharepoint?

PS: Attaching screenshot of the build

[Build number screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSk1h.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please check the build number of your SharePoint farm using PowerShell Get-SPFarm | Select BuildVersion and what would be the result?